# how to prevent background-img hidden when apply transform scale function

Tags: css, css-transforms

Recently I want to apply transition and transform to a div and something very wired happened.

My div structure is like this:

```css
    .img img {
      width: 234px;
      height: 140px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      transition: transform .5s; 
    }
     .img img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2); 
    }
    .playWrapper{
      position: absolute;
      height: 32px;
      margin-top: 25%;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .playWrapper .playVideo{
      background: url('http://lorempixel.com/20/20/') 0 0 no-repeat;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="img nlist">
     <div class="playWrapper">
         <div class="playVideo"></div>
        </div> 
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>
```

There is 2 things I cannot figure out how to do it. One is the playVideo div is not aligned center. The other one is when I hover over the img, the img scales, but the playVideo png would disappear, and when I put my mouse out of the img, the scale returned back to 1 and the playVedio png appears again.

Is there anyone who knows how to make the png visiable when hover over the img and how to align center of a div when the parent has to be absolute position?

Comment: your play video appears under the png, have you tried using position:absolute;? or flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One is the playVideo div is not aligned center.

To have everything consistently centered, simply add a `text-align: center` rule to the parent.

> The other one is when I hover over the img, the img scales, but the
>   playVideo png would disappear, and when I put my mouse out of the img,
>   the scale returned back to 1 and the playVedio png appears again.

This can be simply fixed by adding a `z-index` to .`playWrapper` to keep it the top layer within the container.

**CSS Changes**

```
.img { text-align: center; }

.playWrapper { z-index: 1; }
```

**Working Example**

```css
.img {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.img img {
  width: 234px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.playWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.playWrapper .playVideo {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/20/20/') 0 0 no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img nlist">
  <div class="playWrapper">
    <div class="playVideo"></div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
</div>
```